# Workflow Foundation - Literal only supports value types and the immutable type System.String

Tags: c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have the following unit test for a WF code activity called MyCodeActivity:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldRequireParam()
{
    //arrange
    var invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(new MyCodeActivity()
    {
        MyInt = 2,
        MyComplexObject = _complexObject
    });

    //act
    invoker.Invoke();

    //assert
    Assert.Fail("Expected ArgumentException");
}
```

When I run the test I get the following exception

> 'Literal< MyComplexObject>': Literal only supports value types and the immutable type System.String.  The type MyComplexObject cannot be used as a literal.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: Maybe this could also help you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2013194

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix the immediate problem:

```
MyComplexObject = _complexObject
```

to

```
MyComplexObject = new InArgument<MyComplexObject>((ctx) => _complexObject)
```

Further reading : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358749.aspx .

**Note:** You should also use the [Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview) package available on NuGet. It makes IOC alot easier (seeing as WF works with the Service Locator pattern and not Dependency Injection)