# literal error while working with c# asp.net/ wf

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I made a drag-and-drop workflow, and got an Literal error while passing an object through the INargument. Any ideas how I can get around this error?

error: 'Literal': Literal only supports value types and the immutable type System.String.  The type System.Object cannot be used as a literal.

I've seen some answers, but all the examples are in hard-coded workflows, and I don't want rewrite the whole workflow in hard-code.

```
WorkflowActivitycheckdb ActEmail = new WorkflowActivitycheckdb { 
    EmailList = AdminsToList, 
    EmailContent = tolist, 
    UserName = name, 
    UnApprovedS = UnApproved, 
    NumberOfUsers = tel, 
    NumberOfAdmins = tel2 
}; 
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(ActEmail);
```

please help.

Comment: What code throws this error?

Comment: the "WorkflowInvoker.Invoke()" code...

Comment: Do you mind sharing this code or are we going to guess?

Comment: haha, here's the code...

Comment: all the inArguments go through to the workflow, except for the "Emailist= AdminsToList"...

Comment: The Emaillist is set as an array on the workflow side...and the AdminsToList is an set array of Emails...

Comment: I tried to change the AdminsToList to a list object, but neither the object or the array will go through to the workflow, then it throws the literal error...

Comment: A bit of googling brings this back: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tilovell/archive/2010/06/02/literal-lt-t-gt-and-reference-types.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554084/workflow-foundation-literal-only-supports-value-types-and-the-immutable-type-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WorkflowActivitycheckdb ActEmail = new WorkflowActivitycheckdb { 
    EmailList = new InArgument<Whateveryourobjectis>( x=> AdminsToList), 
    EmailContent = tolist, 
    UserName = name, 
    UnApprovedS = UnApproved, 
    NumberOfUsers = tel, 
    NumberOfAdmins = tel2 
}; 
WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(ActEmail);
```

gl

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing that particular line outside the object initializer.

Eg :

```
ActEmail.EmailList = AdminsToList;
```

Make the EmailList class *[immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352471/how-do-i-create-an-immutable-class)*.